# iPHONE SDK - Subtracting a time given another time

Tags: iphone

having trouble with this. i need to come up with a logic code.

How do i, given 2 set of times. subtract one from the other and change it all to seconds.

Lets say i have '12:00:00' and '15:00:00'
Now i want to subtract 12:00:00 from 15:00:00 so the result will be 03:00:00. Then change it all to seconds so that will be 10800 seconds

i already have two sets of time in an NSString after being Formatted with a NSDateFormatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need to look for : [NSDate -(NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceDate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-timeIntervalSinceDate_)

Convert your string to an NSDate and call this method [thisDate timeIntervalSinceDate:thatDate] will return you an NSTimeInterval, type double

Comment: hi . thx for replying. I need some help with converting the NSString to an NSDate. could u share some sample code?

Comment: ah ok nvm i found the dateFromString:String method

Comment: ah i have another problem, how do i assign it to a variable? sorry for asking but im new to obj-c

Comment: What is "it"? You mean the NSTimeInterval? It is not an object, you have to use NSTimeInterval time = [thisDate timeIntervalSinceDate:thatDate]; or you can use double. But I prefer NSTimeInterval

Comment: im getting null  or 0 when NSLogged. here is the code that im using

Comment: NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
 
 NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
 NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-3*60*60];
NSDate *now2 = [[NSDate alloc] init];

Comment: NSString *theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:now];
 NSString *theTimeNOW = [timeFormat stringFromDate:now2];

 NSDate *cDate1 = [timeFormat dateFromString:theTime];
 NSDate *cDate2 = [timeFormat dateFromString:theTimeNOW];

 NSTimeInterval time = [cDate2 timeIntervalSinceDate:cDate1];
 NSLog(@"time IN COREPLOT VIEW ~~~CONTROLLER~~ %@",time);

Comment: No, it is not an object, for sure, use %f for double. I mean this line : NSLog(@"time IN COREPLOT VIEW ~~~CONTROLLER~~ %@",time);

Comment: And then, why do you need to convert to NSString just to convert back to NSDate?

Comment: oh yeah . good point. haha , guess i was thinking too much about it that i didn't noticed that.